Controlling of PackageReference attributes on NuGet package installation
I have a NuGet package for plugins development for some application (let's call it DevKit).
When people create their plugins and distribute them, the DLL of my DevKit should not be included into the distribution. But it still should be possible to call the API of the DevKit during development. I know it is possible to achieve such behavior via adding attributes to the PackageReference after the package is installed.
For example:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Tum4ik.JustClipboardManager.PluginDevKit" Version="3.2.24181.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  ...
  
</Project>

I also know it is possible to add <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency> to my DevKit csproj file, but that will add these attributes on the DevKit package installation:
<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>

And that is not my goal, becaus compile assets are not available.
So, is there a way to configure NuGet package to automatically add these properties on its installation?:
<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
<IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>

